# How to continue android espresso tests after reporting failures? Below is the code I am using for repeating a test for multiple inputs

Tags: android, user-interface, automation, android-espresso

Below is the code snippet

```
@Test
fun verifyInvalidAge() {
    for (i in 15..30) {
        onView(withId(R.id.editTextNumber)).perform(replaceText(i.toString()))
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click())
        onView(withId(R.id.statusTextView)).check(matches(withText("You can't drink yet :(")))
    }
}
```

I want to report failures if any for any of the input and continue test.

Want to see the test report based on my inputs after test execution.

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this you would want to use what is called Parameterized Tests.

These tests run through a set of values and run the test for each value in the set.

Below is a sample:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class FibonacciTest {
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { 0, 0 }, { 1, 1 }, { 2, 1 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 3 }, { 5, 5 }, { 6, 8 }  
           });
    }

    private int fInput;

    private int fExpected;

    public FibonacciTest(int input, int expected) {
        this.fInput = input;
        this.fExpected = expected;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(fExpected, Fibonacci.compute(fInput));
    }
}
```

More details are here:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests